# Android studio adding custom adapter to AsyncTask

Tags: android, mysql, listview, android-asynctask

So i have a AsyncTask that pulls data from a Mysql database and displays it, currently this works fine but i need to change the simple adapter to a custom adapter so i can do more with what is displayed. But i'm not sure what i need to change in order to get my custom adapter to work with my AsyncTask.

```
public class SearchFor extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

DBManager db;
ListView lv;

myAdapter myAdapter;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> attractionList;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> transportList;

// url to get all attraction list
private static String url_all_attractions = "http://10.0.2.2/TravelApp/get_all_attractions.php";
private static String url_all_transport = "http://10.0.2.2/TravelApp/get_all_transport.php";

// JSON Node names for attraction
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_ATTRACTION = "attraction";
private static final String TAG_ATTRACTIONID = "Id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "Name";
private static final String TAG_TYPE = "Type";
private static final String TAG_LOCATION = "Location";
private static final String TAG_OPENING = "OpeningTime";
private static final String TAG_CLOSING = "ClosingTime";
private static final String TAG_NEARBYSTOP = "NearbyStop";
private static final String TAG_LATITUDE = "Latitude";
private static final String TAG_LONGITUDE = "Longitude";

//JSON Node names for transport
private static final String TAG_TRANSPORT = "transport";
private static final String TAG_TRANSPORTID = "Id";
private static final String TAG_TIME = "Time";
private static final String TAG_NEXTSTOP = "NextStop";
private static final String TAG_PHONENUMBER = "PhoneNumber";

// attraction JSONArray
JSONArray attraction = null;
JSONArray transport = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_for);

    db = new DBManager(this);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    attractionList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    transportList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_search);
    this.registerForContextMenu(lv);
}


@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    if(v.getId()== R.id.list_search ){
        this.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_menu_more,menu);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuBookmark:
            testAdd();
            break;
        case R.id.menuDirections:
            break;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_button, menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.optionsmenu,menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if(id == R.id.go_home){
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),QavelNav.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    if (item.isChecked())
        item.setChecked(false);
    else
        item.setChecked(true);

    if(id == R.id.attractionSub1){
        new LoadAllAttractions().execute();
    }else if(id == R.id.attractionSub2){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Pubs", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else if(id == R.id.attractionSub3){

    }else if(id == R.id.attractionSub4){

    }else if(id == R.id.transportSub1){
        new LoadAllTransport().execute();
    }else if(id == R.id.transportSub2){

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,
                                int position, long id) {

            System.out.println(position);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 */
class LoadAllAttractions extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SearchFor.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading attractions. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    /**
     * getting All attraction from url
     */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_attractions, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Attractions: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // attraction found
                // Getting Array of Products
                attraction = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ATTRACTION);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < attraction.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = attraction.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ATTRACTIONID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String type = c.getString(TAG_TYPE);
                    String location = c.getString(TAG_LOCATION);
                    String opening = c.getString(TAG_OPENING);
                    String closing = c.getString(TAG_CLOSING);
                    String nearbyStop1 = c.getString(TAG_NEARBYSTOP);
                    String latitude = c.getString(TAG_LATITUDE);
                    String longitude = c.getString(TAG_LONGITUDE);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ATTRACTIONID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_TYPE, type);
                    map.put(TAG_LOCATION, location);
                    map.put(TAG_OPENING,opening);
                    map.put(TAG_CLOSING,closing);
                    map.put(TAG_NEARBYSTOP, nearbyStop1);
                    map.put(TAG_LATITUDE, latitude);
                    map.put(TAG_LONGITUDE, longitude);
                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    attractionList.add(map);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        final ArrayList<Adapter> listData = new ArrayList<Adapter>();
        listData.clear();
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all attraction
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        SearchFor.this, attractionList,
                        R.layout.list_attractions, new String[]{TAG_ATTRACTIONID,
                        TAG_NAME,TAG_TYPE,TAG_LOCATION,TAG_OPENING,TAG_CLOSING,TAG_NEARBYSTOP,TAG_LATITUDE,TAG_LONGITUDE},
                        new int[]{R.id.Attractionid, R.id.tvAttractionName, R.id.tvAttractionType, R.id.tvAttractionLocation,R.id.tvAttractionOpening,R.id.tvAttractionClosing,R.id.tvAttractionNearbyStop1});
                // updating listview

                //myAdapter = new myAdapter(listData);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        });

    }

}

class LoadAllTransport extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SearchFor.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Transport. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    /**
     * getting All attraction from url
     */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_transport, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Transport: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // attraction found
                // Getting Array of Products
                transport = json.getJSONArray(TAG_TRANSPORT);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < transport.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = transport.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_TRANSPORTID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String type = c.getString(TAG_TYPE);
                    String location = c.getString(TAG_LOCATION);
                    String time = c.getString(TAG_TIME);
                    String nextStop = c.getString(TAG_NEXTSTOP);
                    String phoneNumber = c.getString(TAG_PHONENUMBER);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_TRANSPORTID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_TYPE, type);
                    map.put(TAG_LOCATION, location);
                    map.put(TAG_TIME,time);
                    map.put(TAG_NEXTSTOP,nextStop);
                    map.put(TAG_PHONENUMBER, phoneNumber);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    transportList.add(map);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all attraction
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        SearchFor.this, transportList,
                        R.layout.list_transport, new String[]{TAG_TRANSPORTID,
                        TAG_NAME,TAG_TYPE,TAG_LOCATION,TAG_TIME,TAG_NEXTSTOP,TAG_PHONENUMBER},
                        new int[]{R.id.transportid, R.id.tvTransportName, R.id.tvTransportType, R.id.tvTransportLocation,R.id.tvTransportPhone});
                // updating listview
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}

public void testAdd(){
    TextView TextName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvAttractionName);
    System.out.println(TextName.getText().toString());
}

public void addAttraction(View v){

    TextView TextName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvAttractionName);
    System.out.println(TextName.getText().toString());

    TextView TextType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAttractionType);
    TextView TextLocation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvAttractionLocation);
    TextView TextOpening = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvAttractionOpening);
    TextView TextClosing = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvAttractionClosing);
    TextView TextNearbyStop = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvAttractionNearbyStop1);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DBManager.ColName,TextName.getText().toString());
    values.put(DBManager.ColType,TextType.getText().toString());
    values.put(DBManager.ColLocation,TextLocation.getText().toString());
    values.put(DBManager.ColOpening,TextOpening.getText().toString());
    values.put(DBManager.ColClosing,TextClosing.getText().toString());
    values.put(DBManager.ColNearbyStop,TextNearbyStop.getText().toString());

    long id = db.Insert("BookmarkAttraction",values);
    if (id > 0)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Added to bookmarks", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"cannot insert", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

public void addTransport(View v){
    TextView TextName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTransportName);
    TextView TextType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTransportType);
    TextView TextLocation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTransportLocation);
    TextView TextPhoneNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTransportPhone);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DBManager.ColName,TextName.getText().toString());
    values.put(DBManager.ColType,TextType.getText().toString());
    values.put(DBManager.ColLocation,TextLocation.getText().toString());
    values.put(DBManager.ColPhoneNumber,TextPhoneNumber.getText().toString());

    long id = db.Insert("BookmarkTransport",values);
    if (id > 0)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Added to bookmarks", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"cannot insert", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

class myAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public ArrayList<Adapter> listItem;

    public myAdapter(ArrayList<Adapter> listItem) {
        this.listItem = listItem;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listItem.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater myInflator = getLayoutInflater();
        final View myView = myInflator.inflate(R.layout.list_attractions, null);

        final Adapter ac = listItem.get(position);

        TextView attractionId = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.Attractionid);
        attractionId.setText(ac.ID);

        TextView Name = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.tvAttractionName);
        Name.setText(ac.Name);

        TextView Type = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.tvAttractionType);
        Type.setText(ac.Type);

        TextView Location = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.tvAttractionLocation);
        Location.setText(ac.Location);

        TextView Opening = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.tvAttractionOpening);
        Opening.setText(ac.Opening);

        TextView Closing = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.tvAttractionClosing);
        Closing.setText(ac.Closing);

        TextView NearbyStop1 = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.tvAttractionNearbyStop1);
        NearbyStop1.setText(ac.NearbyStop);

        return myView;
    }
}
}
```

The parts of interest are the custom adapter (myAdapter) located at the bottom and the first AsyncTask is what im trying to convert to a custom adapter. The onPostExecute is where the the simple adapter is and probably where i need to reference the custom adapter but need help with this

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're using a single adapter for both of your needs.

Did you think about creating a two Custom Adapter classes for your two AsyncTasks.

Also few suggestions:
1. You can use Loader Callbacks and Cursor loader If you're using AsyncTask for DB fetching.
2. preExecute and postExecute already run on UI thread. So no need of runOnUIThread call there.
3. Use ViewHolder pattern in the Adapters getView method for better optimization.

Comment: Thank you for the tips about the runOnUIThread call and i will look into the ViewHolder pattern, but how do i implement Loader Callbacks with what i have, so i.e. what would i need to replace./change to accomodate them and how would i then link the loaded results with my custom adapter